# How To Simulate Scanner Input From Another Class (A Test Class) Without Interfering With That Actual Class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputstream

I want to test a message method from another class, a test class, but in an independent way so that the test class calls on the message method and inputs a predefined value for the number of lines and the actual message. So when the method is called, the value 1 is inputted in console when the line number is asked, and then afterwards when the message is asked, the string "hi how are you doing today" is inputted in the console. Below I have the message method from one class and the part of the test class that will test the user input.

So my question is, how can i get the test class to call on the message method (which is in another class) and when that message method runs, input values into the scanner as needed, and then that message method continues to run till the end.

I'm thinking it has to do with the input stream. However, since I'm trying to input values in a scanner in another class, it doesn't work. I have seen similar questions relating to simulated scanner input, but those are for the same class and directly talk to the scanner in the same method. I want these things to be separate, so that if the test class is deleted/removed, the class where the message method is in would still work like normal.

[Click Here To See The Console For The Message Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQZxM.png)

```
public static String message() {
    //Asks the user for the number of lines in the message
    Scanner lines = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter how number of lines in the message: ");   

    //if user doesn't enter a number, it keeps asking for one
    while(!lines.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.print("Error! Please Choose a Number:");
        lines.next();
    }

    //the number of lines is stores in an array where each index is a line
    String[] input = new String[lines.nextInt()];
    System.out.println("Enter the message: ");
    lines.nextLine(); //consuming the <enter> from input above

    //each index is given a line to store
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i] = lines.nextLine();
    }
    //message if turned into a one line string and returned
    String message = (Arrays.toString(input).replaceAll("\\W", "")).toLowerCase();
    return message;
}
```

String keyTest5 = "1";
String keyTest6 = "adbh, sdba";

```
    SarmanEncryption inputOutput= new SarmanEncryption();
    inputOutput.message();
    InputStream num = new ByteArrayInputStream(keyTest5.getBytes());
    System.setIn(Integer.parseInt(num));
    InputStream message = new ByteArrayInputStream(keyTest6.getBytes());
    System.setIn(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider rewriting your code to make it easily testable.  If you are testing the message method then you could pass input/output streams to the method.

You could also do this (inject the dependency on in/out streams) in the constructor of your object that has method under test.

Be careful about closing your streams.

Comment: I've been thinking about passing input/output as the parameters in the message method, but i don't fully understand how to do so. Could you please provide an example of the code. Also, for some reason, I get an error when I try to close lines scanner at the end. Why is that? Thanks for the response